# asp.net mvc 3 client side required validation works randomly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Is it true that jquery unobtrusive client side validation doesn't work correctly till the first form submit is performed?
I've got issues when form is not being submitted and when I enter some data into a required field and then remove it I've got the validation applied randomly: sometimes yes sometimes no.
Is it a common issue and is possible to initialize the validation before form submit or disable it in order not to get this unpredictable behavior?

Comment: It would be a lot more practical if you could reproduce the problem with minimal code and share that code.  Given what's here, all anybody can do is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is dynamic content which causes the validation problem, then you can use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.validate.unobtrusive.parse("#dynamicId");
</script>
```

if it is a partial view then you can do this:

```
@{
  if( ViewContext.FormContext == null ){
   ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
  }
}
```